Cache Lock Not Enforced on Simultaneous Recipe Updates in Duplicate Tabs
I'm facing an issue with the cache lock implementation on my recipe edit page in Laravel. My goal is to ensure that only one recipe can be updated at a time. However, when I have two duplicate tabs open with the same user logged in, and I attempt to update the recipe simultaneously in both tabs, the recipe is updated in both instances without enforcing the cache lock as intended.
public function updateRecipe()
{
    // Unique lock key based on user ID and recipe ID
    $lockKey = 'recipe-update-' . auth()->user()->id;
    $lock = Cache::lock($lockKey, 20);

    try {
        // Try to acquire the lock
        if ($lock->get()) {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $this->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'ingredients' => 'required|string',
                'description' => 'required|string',
                'image' => 'nullable|image|max:2048', // 2MB Max
            ]);

            if ($this->image) {
                $imagePath = $this->image->store('recipes', 'public');
            }

            // Attempt to find and update the recipe
            $recipe = Recipe::findOrFail($this->recipeId);
            $recipe->update([
                'name' => $this->name,
                'ingredients' => $this->ingredients,
                'description' => $this->description,
                'image_path' => $this->image ? $imagePath : $recipe->image_path
            ]);
            DB::commit();

            session()->flash('message', 'Recipe updated successfully.');
            return redirect()->route('index');
        } else {
            // If the lock is not acquired
            session()->flash('update_error_lock', 'The recipe is currently being updated by someone else. Please try again later.');
            $lock->release();
            sleep(3);
            return redirect()->route('index');
        }
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        session()->flash('update_error', 'The recipe you are trying to update does not exist.');
        return redirect()->route('index');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        session()->flash('update_error', 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
}


Environment:
Laravel 11.x
Livewire
Question:
Why is the cache lock not being enforced when updating the recipe simultaneously in two duplicate tabs, and how can I ensure that only one update is processed at a time?
What I Tried:
I implemented a cache lock using the Cache::lock() method to ensure that only one recipe can be updated at a time. I expected that if two duplicate tabs attempted to update the recipe simultaneously, the cache lock would prevent the second update until the first one was complete.
What I Expected:
I expected the cache lock to enforce a single update process, meaning if one tab was already updating the recipe, the second tab would be blocked or would receive an error indicating that the recipe is currently being updated.
What Actually Happened:

Despite the cache lock implementation, both tabs were able to update the recipe simultaneously, resulting in the recipe being updated twice without the lock being enforced.


Can you please simplify your code a bit to make this reproducible? You have a sleep and redirects which make this difficult to test. Also, you're releasing the lock in the "else" block; shouldn't you be releasing it in the main block that acquired it?
